# Relation between dyi/dei and its leverage (hii)

Tags: derivative, leverage

Althought I have tried in different ways, I have not been able to show that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}Y_i}{\mathrm{d}e_i} = \frac{1}{1 - l_{ii}}$$

$e_i$ is equal to [image]

$l_{ii}$ is the $i-th$ element of the diagonal of the "Hat matrix" **H**.

Also, I was able to show that [image]. I think it could help but I don't really know how.

Pd: I'm sorry for the format, and I will try to improve it.

Comment: (1) Please see the link to help when in editing mode and search out the MathJax help: it will show you how to format mathematical expressions for readability.  (2) Could you explain in what sense observations can be considered functions of "residuals"?  What exactly do you mean by a "residual"?  Could you perhaps be confusing this with the error term in an ordinary least squares regression, where the error is treated as a variable instead of a random variable?

Comment: I have formatted the first image for you, so that you have something to emulate.  But we still need to know what you mean by "$e_i.$"